# The "left" tag works but the top only works when i set it as px and doesnt when i set as %

Tags: html, css

When trying to set the distance of the paragraph from the top of the page it only works when its set as a pixel value and not when i set it as %. It somehow works with left though

I've tried the % but hasn't worked

```css
.para1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 70%;
  top: 30%;
  left: 9%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="para1">
  <p>If you're reading this I just would like to say a huge thank you for taking the time to want to know who's behind UnixCast. I'm a full-time student with a big passion for learning. I enjoy studying physics and hope to get a degree in astrophysics sometime
    in the future. I've always had a passion for creating content online. From when YouTube was at the start of its big popularity boom, I fell in love with the idea of sharing content freely for everyone to see. My goals for my content are simple:
  </p>
</div>
```

Expected results are to get the text to be responsive to whatever top % I give.

Answer (score 1):

Well because your `<div>` needs a height. And the rest of your css has to be for the `<p>` not the `<div>`.

**Example**

```css
.para1{
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

p {
  top: 80%;
  left: 9%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 70%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="para1">
            <p>If you're reading this I just would like to say a huge thank you for taking the time to want to know who's behind UnixCast. I'm a full-time student with a big passion for learning. I enjoy studying physics and hope to get a degree in astrophysics sometime in the future. I've always had a passion for creating content online. From when YouTube was at the start of its big popularity boom, I fell in love with the idea of sharing content freely for everyone to see. My goals for my content are simple:
          </p>
    </div>
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tsLgh6z/)

**Update**

New [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tsLgh6z/2/)

Comment: When I do that the head gets messed up and the other pragraphs I have get messed up too

Comment: give it an id or class so you specify that paragraph

Comment: check my new fiddle

Comment: Thanks for that. Even by doing this the top command doesnt work

Comment: what do you mean??? My answer is correct so could you accept it as an answer?